# Export the tables from pdf to excel?

Tags: c#

How do i export only the table contents to excel file through C# programming?
I am currently extracting all the contents from PDFs using PDFNET SDK ,but couldn't able to read the table as a tabular structure

Comment: there is no real tabular structure in PDF... so you will basically to have to resort to some sort of "table recognition"... which by definition will produce some correct and some incorrect results...

Answer (score 2):

I know have not used the SDK for this product, but I have used the stand alone product. It read the content of a PDF into a spreadsheet (many export options).

The product is OmniPage by Nuance http://australia.nuance.com/for-business/by-product/omnipage/index.htm.

there is an SDK with free evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Using bytescount PDF Extractor SDK we can be able to extract the whole page as below,

```
        CSVExtractor extractor = new CSVExtractor();
        extractor.RegistrationName = "demo";
        extractor.RegistrationKey = "demo";

        TableDetector tdetector = new TableDetector();
        tdetector.RegistrationKey = "demo";
        tdetector.RegistrationName = "demo";

            // Load the document
        extractor.LoadDocumentFromFile("C:\\sample.pdf");
        tdetector.LoadDocumentFromFile("C:\\sample.pdf");

           int pageCount = tdetector.GetPageCount();

            for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
            {
                int j = 1;

                    do
                    {
                            extractor.SetExtractionArea(tdetector.GetPageRect_Left(i),
                            tdetector.GetPageRect_Top(i),
                            tdetector.GetPageRect_Width(i),
                            tdetector.GetPageRect_Height(i)
                        );

                        // and finally save the table into CSV file
                        extractor.SavePageCSVToFile(i, "C:\\page-" + i + "-table-" + j + ".csv");
                        j++;
                    } while (tdetector.FindNextTable()); // search next table
            }
```

since it is an old post, hope it would help others.

Answer (score 1):

Above answer（John） works,it is really useful.

But i use bytescount PDF Extrator SDK tools instead of using code.

By the way,the tool will generate a lot of sheet in one excel file.

You can use code below in excel to generate as one sheet.

```
Sub ConvertAsOne()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For j = 1 To Sheets.Count
If Sheets(j).Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
   X = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   Sheets(j).UsedRange.Copy Cells(X, 1)
End If
Next
Range("B1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "succeed！", vbInformation, "note"
End Sub
```