# Importing pdf to excel in exact format

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, worksheet

I have this code but I want to copy and paste PDF file in exact format to excel not in single line or column, I mean to say if I have a table with two columns and 16 rows in PDF format I want to paste it in exact format to excel using vba. the below code is not working properly it is selecting but not pasting the data to excel also I'm not able to paste it in exact format as PDF to excel.

**kindly help me with this**

Please refer the PDF file with this code I want to paste in exact format to excel.

[image]

```
Sub Shell_Copy_Paste()

   Dim o As Variant
   Dim wkSheet As Worksheet

   Set wkSheet = ActiveSheet

   o = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe C:\Users\saurabh.ad.sharma\Desktop\red.pdf", vbNormalFocus)

   Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)) 'Wait for Acrobat to load

   SendKeys "^a"   'Select All
   SendKeys "^c"   'Copy
   SendKeys "%{F4}"    'Close shell application

   wkSheet.Range("B5").Select
   SendKeys "^v"   'Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "exact format"?

Comment: i mean in same way as given in pdf . it will not paste it in one cell all the values of pdf

Comment: When you copy and paste manually from the PDF does it work the way you want into Excel?

Comment: no it is not .. but if i paste in word from pdf and then paste it into excel then it is working . can you give some code for that or anything it will be really helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export the tables from pdf to excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925477/export-the-tables-from-pdf-to-excel)

Comment: Try https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/689781/How-to-find-and-extract-PDF-table-to-excel-file-in